# Lift the 15-points reputation requirement for upvoting answers if the question was asked by yourself?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, up-votes, rep-requirement

I know the requirement is there to avoid users upvoting their own answers with fake accounts; but this has the side effect that a legitimate new user can't upvote good answers to a question he/she asked, until his/her reputation reach at least 15 points.

Should this requirement be lifted for upvoting answers to questions asked by the same users?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 15 rep prerequisite helps ensure that the user has at least some basic understanding of what voting is for. Even on their own questions, this matters. There's more at stake than just a little rep, votes are what help people who don't have a clue make decisions on what answer to try.

New users often don't know what votes are for, consider this exchange:

> **Q**: How do I do X?
>
> **A**: You need to post more code or we can't help you.
>
> **Comment**: OK +1 I will post more code.

Comment: I find it difficult to imagine people could not have even a basic understanding about how a site works before using that site... but you're right, it actually happens everywhere :-/

Comment: Even some experienced users think that votes are "rewards" for "trying to help", when in fact they are meant to measure the quality and/or correctness of an answer.

Answer (score 4):

> Should this requirement be lifted for upvoting answers to questions asked by the same users?

I don't really see why - you have to admit gaining 15 reputation points is pretty easy on Stack Overflow, so for everyone who isn't a complete hit-and-run user (who won't upvote anyway) this is only a very temporary issue.